# how to set data in service in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

In a table I am adding items such as product and price. I need to set the added data in service . can you please tell  how to set the added data in service

routerApp.controller('products', function ($scope,myservice) {

```
$scope.items = [];

 $scope.addRow = function(){
```

$scope.items.push({'Products':$scope.Products,'Price':$scope.Price});

```
 }
```

});

service.js

routerApp.factory('myservice',function() {

```
var products =[]
var price=[]
var quantity=[]

var addProduct = function(data) {
  products.push(data);
}

var addPrice = function(data) {
  price.push(data);
}

var addQuantity = function(data) {
  quantity.push(data);
 }
```

Comment: can any one write service for set data in table

Comment: Please add some code and explain what you have tried to accomplish this and what is going wrong.

Comment: You're going to get downvoted unless you show some code and what you've already tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

you use getter and setters in your services.
Set data using setters and get it using getters simple.

Something like this...

```
var mod = angular.module('service', []);
mod.factory('sservice', ['$http',
        function($http){
      var anyName;
     var setData = function(data) {
               anyName=data;
            }
 }
    ]);
```